# Calling functions from main() in c++

Tags: c++

I came across a program with 10 header and 10 source files. I read in my text book that the functions are called from main. But how can I pass data to so many functions from main()?

Comment: That depends entirely on what kind of data it is and the purpose for which the functions need it.  Perhaps you can give an example, in pseudocode even.

Comment: The same way you pass data to any function.

Comment: I recommend you continue reading your textbook...I'm sure everything will get clear then.

Comment: Right question Neil. May be with that textbook Supriyo will never get the point Maximilian Mayerl :).

Answer (score 14):

Functions don't necessarily need to called from main. They can be called by other functions. For example:

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x*x;
}

int bar(int x)
{
   return foo(x) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = bar(42);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `foo()` is never called directly from `main()`.

Comment: Thanks. But my program has 100 classes and more than 1000 functions spread over many files. How to call them from main()? What is the procedure adopted?

Comment: Many of those classes and functions will depend on other classes and functions, and so on. I suspect that you only need to call a few top-level ones from main, and it will trickle down from there. You'll have to study the code to figure out what your "entry points" are.

Comment: A nice way to quickly navigate through code, is to run the code through a documentation program called Doxygen. It will produce HTML documentation files with lots of hyperlinks, as well as header/class dependency graphs. Make sure you enable the SOURCE_BROWSER option, so that it produces HTML versions of the source code with hyperlinks to all classes, structs, functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, this phrase isn't correct, but I guess what was meant to be said could be rephrased like *"Every function or class method that you implement and use would be **somehow** called from your `main()` routine"*

And ***somehow*** in this context would actually mean *directly* or *indirectly* - via other functions / function wrappers.

Anyway, the idea should be clear - any significant action that is done in your application is actually done using some function call from your `main()` routine, which is sometimes also called ***application root*** (*try to think of your application as a tree of function calls and then your `main()` function would be right in the top of your tree).*