# Calling functions from main() in c++

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling functions from main() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939586/calling-functions-from-main-in-c)

Hello.
I have a programme that has about 100 classes and more than 1000 functions spread over 20 header and source code files. What I want to know is that how I can pass arguments to so many functions in so many files? What is the procedure adopted for this in main()?
Regards,
Supriyo

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Calling functions from main() in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939586/calling-functions-from-main-in-c) (same user, too)

Comment: @James: No, this isn't a duplicate.  It seems that the program has grown by an order of magnitude since the last question.

Comment: Not a dup, looks like he's asking about how to grab command line args and pass them to functions.

Comment: @Mark:  Nah; he's just changed units of measurement from files to classes.  ;-)  @Robert:  That's not what he asked.  That would be a more reasonable question, though.

Comment: @Robert No mention of command line in the question.

Comment: @Michael Why did you remove the link to the dupe? Rolled back.

Comment: @Neil I meant to remove just one, I was in the middle of fixing it when you rolled back

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Boost.Program_options module](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: Hello. I am in urgent need of an answer to my quetion which I have not got. Anybody please answer. Regards Supriyo