# How to pass data to many functions

Tags: c++, function

I am new to C++ programming.

Now I have a program that consists of millions of lines of code in thousands of files. But when I saw the main() (command line) it was very small. Now how to pass data to so many million functions from such a small main()? There was no text file for parsing or array of structure that contains a function pointer and a text string etc.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944902/calling-functions-from-main-in-c-closed posted by same user, and closed.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine I have a fifty-thousand-line-long function, called `foo()`.  Now let's say I write a `main` function that's one line long, and just calls `foo()`.  I still have fifty thousand lines of code, but `main` is tiny.

Or let's say I have fifty thousand two-line long functions.  Each one consists of calls to two others.  If `main` calls one of them, it's possible that *all* of them will get called at some point.  That's over a hundred thousand lines of code, with fifty thousand and one functions, and **none** of the functions are longer than two lines.

The size of `main` means nothing.

Comment: +1 for saying that the size of `main` means nothing. Even most girls say size doesn't matter !

Comment: To my knowledge the two cases do not apply in real world programming.
I have a GUI library and an application from it that contains over a million functions. Now how can I pass data to so many of them? The program is running without any compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

First, in a well designed program, there are many small functions. Each of the functions do a small thing and let some other function do the real work.

Second, if a parameter is a struct or an array, it can contain a lot of data. A small number of parameters do not always indicate that little data is passed.

For example, your main() function may look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    options programOptions;
    work result;

    programOptions = parseOptions(argv);
    result = doTheWork(programOptions);
    printResult(result);
}
```

It is hard to tell more without some code or an example what your program does.