# Guide to changing int main()

Tags: c++, int, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling functions from main() in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939586/calling-functions-from-main-in-c)

what are some guidlines to changing int main to call other functions in your code I was told not to use int main2(), int main3() and so on also how do I declare them so that the compiler calls them and recognizes them would it be

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
int main 2()
using namespace std;

int main()
  code here ..... 1st function
int main2()
  code here .... 2nd function
```

or would it be

```
#include <iostream>
int anothername()
int seconddifferentname()
using namespace std;

int anothername()
  code here ..... 1st function
int seconddifferentname()
  code here .... 2nd function
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to name other functions besides "main" itself?

Comment: yes cristian K i do that would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create new functions and call them from main:

```
void foo() {}
void goo() {}

int main()
{
  foo();
  goo();
}
```

There's nothing technically wrong with having `main1` or `main2` methods, but there's only one entry point of a valid C++ program, and that's `main`.